# How can I properly enable slots and scoped slots usage when wrapping a Vuetify component?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I currently do this to enable slots and scoped slots usage.

```html
<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-bind="computedAttrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
  >
    <!-- Cycling through slots -->
    <template v-for="(_, name) in $slots">
      <template :slot="name">
        <slot :name="name"></slot>
      </template>
    </template>

    <!-- Cycling through scoped slots -->
    <template
      v-for="(_, name) in $scopedSlots"
      #[name]="data"
    >
      <slot
        :name="name"
        v-bind="data"
      ></slot>
    </template>

  </v-text-field>
</template>
```

I don't understand why I cannot do this to enable slots usage.

```html
<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-bind="computedAttrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
  >
    <!-- Cycling through slots -->
    <template
      v-for="(_, name) in $slots"
      #[name]
    >
      <slot :name="name"></slot>
    </template>

    <!-- Cycling through scoped slots -->
    <template
      v-for="(_, name) in $scopedSlots"
      #[name]="data"
    >
      <slot
        :name="name"
        v-bind="data"
      ></slot>
    </template>

  </v-text-field>
</template>
```

I saw people doing this, but I don't understand why it doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** I'm using Vue2.

Comment: `#[name]` is equivalent to `v-slot:[name]` which is equivalent to `:slot="name"` - https://devinduct.com/blogpost/59/vue-tricks-passing-slots-to-child-components

Comment: @IVOGELOV I know, but I don't know why, if I replace above code with below code, nothing works anymore.

Comment: Because the `below` code contains only non-scoped slots - while the `above` code contains both scoped and non-scoped slots.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I thought it was clear. Edited.

Comment: Perhaps it's not your fault but an issue with the Vue template compiler ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV no idea, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: I am pretty confident it's not your fault because I see the same effect in my projects.

Comment: @IVOGELOV understood. What triggers me is that some people are able to effectively use what I wrote in the second example.

Comment: If you can get their `package.json` and `babel.config.js` and compare to yours - are there significant differences? It could be the vue-loader, vue-template-compiler, Babel, ESbuild, ....